# PostgreSQL: websearch_to_tsquery precedence / predicate ordering

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

How does precedence work in websearch_to_tsquery? I have below example query:

```
websearch_to_tsquery('exp1 exp2 OR "multi word expression" -weak')
```

The issue I have is that the results include text containing 'weak' because they match 'exp1 exp2'.

However when I remove `OR "multi word expression` eg query being

```
websearch_to_tsquery('exp1 exp2 -weak')
```

then it works as expected and weak is not present in results.

I suspect the initial query is interpreted as

```
(exp1 and exp2) OR ("multi word expression" and not weak)
```

instead of my intention of
(exp1 and exp2) OR ("multi word expression") and not weak

So how would I write the later query using `websearch_to_tsquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how PostgreSQL interprets your query:

```
SELECT websearch_to_tsquery('english', 'exp1 exp2 OR "multi word expression" -weak');

                     websearch_to_tsquery                     
--------------------------------------------------------------
 'exp1' & 'exp2' | 'multi' <-> 'word' <-> 'express' & !'weak'
(1 row)
```

Since `&` ties stronger than `|`, your suspicion is correct.

I don't think that there is a simpler way to express what you want with `websearch_to_tsquery` than

```
exp1 exp2 -weak OR "multi word expression" -weak
```